# Next.js with Prisma: too much entries with findMany

Tags: sql, next.js, prisma

Right now I get all items from a table and display them inside a carousel. The problem is that I have too many entries in that table and the site is loading too slowly.

Is there any solution to get only a few of them, and display them in a random order but without repeating them? Unfortunately, I'm pretty new to Next.js (I work with 13.4) and Prisma. Thank you!

Right now I have in the api folder:

```
const items = await prisma.items.findMany();
```

On the `page.tsx` (homepage) I have a function:

```
async function getItems() {
  ---------------------------
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}
```

I also have a function to shuffle the array I get from `getItems` and after in the main function from page.tsx

```
const items = await getItems();
const shuffleItems = shuffleArray(items );
```

And I return:

```
<Items items={shuffleItems} />
```

And in that component `Items` I have the carousel(I show 3 items at the same time) with all the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `take` and `skip` property to `findMany()`. As an example like so:

```js
const itemsNumber = await prisma.items.count();
const results = await prisma.items.findMany({
  take: 4, // Define the number of items you want
  skip: Math.floor(Math.random() * (itemsNumber - 4)),
})
```

You can read more on the [doc](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/pagination) if you want. The skip part is to get random records, inspired by this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/5886).